# Loading XML file in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am working on a project where I would create an XML file and provide a small Java SDK to client programs mostly to fetch data from it, and some minimal write operations.

The thing is that the XML files can eventually end up containing truck loads of data, so my SDK should be as fast as possible - in loading the document and extracting info from it.

Any pointers on how to get started?

Comment: Let me Google that for you :
 http://www.developerfusion.com/code/2064/a-simple-way-to-read-an-xml-file-in-java/

Comment: Searching stackoverflow, gives this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545619/how-can-i-efficiently-parse-200-000-xml-files-in-java

Comment: You start by taking a look [Simple API for XML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/index.html) and in particular, take a look at [Parsing an XML File using SAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html)

Comment: @saum22 if u want to read xml files why not use xstream ?

Comment: @saum22 - I googled, and found a lot of technologies just like the others are mentioning here already. SAX, xstream etc. I just wanted to know what would be the best way to do it for a large XML!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its depends on your requirement, If You know the XML structure in advanced, you can use Sax parser or DOM parser. But If XML is big enough and structure is unknown, always Stax is best option.

Answer (score 0):

A SAX parser would be the best bet here.